# Get User Detail using Facebook API

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am use this functions for get Facebook user detail

```
    <script>
      function statusChangeCallback(response) {
        console.log('statusChangeCallback');
        console.log(response);
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
          testAPI();
        } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
          document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
            'into this app.';
        } else {
          document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
            'into Facebook.';
        }
      }

      function checkLoginState() {
        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
          statusChangeCallback(response);
        });
      }

      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      FB.init({
        appId      : 'I enter here my aplication ID',
        cookie     : true,  
        xfbml      : true,  
        version    : 'v2.1' 
      });
      FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        statusChangeCallback(response);
      });

      };

  (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

      function testAPI() {
        console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
        FB.api('/me?fields=id,first_name,last_name,email,gender,birthday,bio,hometown,education,quotes,cover,work,devices', function(response) {
          console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name);
          document.getElementById('status').innerHTML =
            'Thanks for logging in, <br /><br />' 
            + response.id + '<br />'
            + response.first_name + '<br />'
            + response.last_name + '<br />'
            + response.name + '<br />'
            + response.email + '<br />'
            + response.gender + '<br />'
            + response.birthday + '<br />'
            + response.bio + '<br />'
            + response.quotes + '<br />'
            + response.location.name + '<br />'
            + response.hometown.name + '<br />'
            ;
        });
      }

    </script>
    <fb:login-button scope="public_profile,email, user_birthday, user_hometown, user_location, user_likes, user_activities, user_education_history, user_work_history, user_about_me" onlogin="checkLoginState();" data-auto-logout-link="true">
    </fb:login-button>
```

But It is work only for me which create this application

for other users some fields is undefined

ex- birthday,bio,quotes,location,hometown,education,work

### In this way output for me(who create application ID)

Thanks for logging in,

677362262358935

Deep

Panchal

Deep Panchal

panchaldeep009@gmail.com

male

10/15/1997

Web Developer, Programmer, Electronics & Communication Engineer.

Be-live in Truth,

Vagra, Gujarat, India

Vagra, Gujarat, India

### But for other User

Thanks for logging in,

XXXXXXXXXXXXXX   (id)

first name

lastname

name

email@mail.com

male

undefined (birthday)

undefined (bio)

undefined (quotes)

undefined (hometown)

undefined (location)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make those other permissions work for everyone, you need to go through a review process with the extended permissions: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login

```
https://developers.facebook.com/apps/[APP-ID]/review-status/
```

...and then hit "Start a Submission". Those permissions need to get approved by Facebook, or they will only work for Users with a role in the App (Admin, Developer, Tester).

Comment: How I can get education name where type collage or highschool

Comment: that would be the "user_education_history" permission

Comment: Oh yes, but it is intermarriage array how to decode that and get name value for each.

Answer (score 1):

It's only working for your user because you must have authorized the application, the scope defines which data your application could access, the other fields are showing up undefined because the app doesn't have permissions.

Please check: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.2

Comment: because i am not deep developer

Comment: check @luschn answer, you must go through the review process to grant your app the posibility of accesing those fields: "f your app asks for more than than public_profile, email and user_friends it will require review by Facebook before your app can be used by people other than the app's developers"

Comment: Thanks.... One more help
      
How I can get education name where type collage or highschool